# How to make a custom markdown syntax for my markdown using remark?

Tags: reactjs, syntax, markdown, custom-component, remarkjs

I want a custom syntax for my markdown so that I can use it with my React Component. I am using using `remark` and `remark-react` to render my markdown into React components. How do a I define a custom syntax for markdown so that I can use it to render my React Component?